# How to plot attributes from a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list of objects belonging to the class `Config` defined as the following:

```py
class Config: 
    def __init__(self,atoms,pH,pOH,proton_count,conjugate_base_count,timestep,totalEnergy,pressure,temperature,nascent_oxy):
        self.atoms=atoms
        self.pH=pH
        self.pOH=pOH
        self.proton_count=proton_count
        self.conjugate_base_count=conjugate_base_count
        self.nascent_oxy=nascent_oxy
        self.timestep=timestep
        self.totalEnergy=totalEnergy
        self.pressure=pressure
        self.temperature=temperature
```

I want to plot the pH, pOH, proton_count, nascent_oxy against the timestep. One way is to make a list out of all the attributes and do the following :

```py
list1=[x.pH for x in configs]
list1=[x.pOH for x in configs]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this - in terms of memory and reducing the hardcoding?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to reduce the amount of code is to wrap the attribute-getting process in a function:

```py
def get_attribute_values(list_of_objects, attribute):
    return [getattr(obj, attribute) for obj in list_of_objects]
```

Then when you construct your plot, you can loop over your list of objects to dynamically add data to it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

attributes = ['ph', 'pOH', 'proton_count', 'conjugate_base_count', 'nascent_oxy', 'totalEnergy', 'pressure', 'temperature']
x_axis = get_attribute_values(configs, 'timestep')   
for attr in attributes:
    y_axis = get_attribute_values(configs, attr)
    plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, label=attr)
plt.xlabel('timestep')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.title('Multi-line plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```